# Not able to run npx command without installing create-next-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, npx

I am trying to create a nextjs project and initializing it using npx command:
`npx create-next-app@latest ./`

As per my understanding, npx does not require to install any package locally and it uses them from npm registry. But here in this case, on running the above command it says:
`Need to install the following packages:        create-next-app@13.4.9`

My current node version is: `18.16.1` and npm version is: `9.8.0`

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It won't install the package locally. But it still needs to get the package in order to execute the package...

Comment: @VLAZ there was a .dist file created in the same folder, after deleting that everything works fine without installing anything explicitly. Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

npx doesn't install packages, in the sense that it doesn't permanently download them to your global or per-project `node_modules`. As you said, it automatically downloads packages off of the NPM registry and executes them (if they're not already part of your local `node_modules`).

However, it has to do *something* with the packages that it downloads, as part of this process - it isn't very practical to download a bunch of compressed package archive off the Internet and directly execute their contents in memory.  It also would be noticeably slower if NPX had to re-download every package from scratch every time you ran it.

There are also risks with automatically downloading and running - for example, [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting) could mean that an attacker picks a package name one keystroke removed from `create-react-app` and hope that you make a typo when you run `npx create-react-app`.

Because of these considerations, NPX maintains a cache directory, and it prompts you to "install" packages the first time it downloads them and caches them, to give you a chance to confirm the package name and catch typos. After the package has been downloaded, NPX won't prompt you again.